# Power BI text to date in "mmm-yy" format

Tags: powerbi

I have an excel file having a column with Text format values like Jan-18, Dec-19, Feb-20. I want to convert it to a date format  but when I am trying to make this column a date format it printing 1/18/2021, 12/19/2021,2/20/2021. Basically its considering Jan as month(1), 18 as Date, & making all year as 2021 deafult.

Can someone help?

```
Original(text)    After Date conversion        Desired format
    Jan-18        1/18/2021                    01/01/2018
    Feb-19        2/19/2021                    01/02/2019
    Mar-20        3/20/2021                    01/03/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
DATE(2018, MONTH(convertedDate), 1)
```

This will convert your converted date to the first day of the relevant month in 2018. This is stored in Power BI as a datetime object. If you want to show that value in dd/MM/yyyy format you can do it by selecting correct `Format` in the top menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you load in the `Original` column as text, try this trick:

```
Desired format = DATEVALUE ( "1-" & [Original] )
```

Appending the `"1-"` to the beginning gives it a day of the month and forces it to recognize the last digits as the year.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue , while changing the format instead of using Date use the last option i.e "Using Locale... " -> in that change the Data Type from Text -> Date, and Locale to English(United Kingdom) -> Hit ok. [Earlier Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIq6K.png)    [,What should  be the desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brkCw.png) .This worked for me!